# Creating a typed template variable from a generic directive

Tags: angular

I would like to have names of parameters of a specific back end route available in my template when working with forms.
My idea is that by passing name of a route, e.g. `GetReservations`, to a custom directive, I would have access to parameter names of that route, e.g. `date: string` and `time: string`.

```html
<form [backend-route]="'GetReservations'" #params>
  <label>Date</label>
  <input [name]="params.date" type="text"/>
  <label>Time</label>
  <input [name]="params.time" type="text"/>
</form>
```

Is it possible, using this or some other way, to have a template variable `params` with some desired type?
I haven't had much experience with Angular's template syntax, so I am not sure what is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Instead of using an attribute directive, using a structural directive let's you declare template variables, and by using `ngTemplateContextGuard`, you can set their type.

```html
<form *backendRoute="'GetReservations'; let params;">
```

```js
@Directive({selector: '[backendRoute]'})
export class RouteDirective<TRouteName extends keyof Actions & keyof ActionResults> {

    @Input('backendRoute') typeToken: TRouteName | [TRouteName, (result: ActionResults[TRouteName]) => void];
    
    constructor(private tpl: TemplateRef<Context<Actions[TRouteName]>>,
                private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    static ngTemplateContextGuard<TRouteName extends keyof Actions & keyof ActionResults>(dir: RouteDirective<TRouteName>,
                                     ctx: unknown): ctx is Context<Actions[TRouteName]> {
        return true
    };
}

// Not yet sure how this works
class Context<T> {
    $implicit!: T;
    subscribe!: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.$implicit = value;
        this.subscribe = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: for anyone trying to copy something like this, make sure that 'Actions' and 'ActionResults' are exported - otherwise the template won't be able to see them. I had something similar to this with two different versions where for one the type was exported and for the other it wasn't. Even having them side by side it took me way too long to figure out the difference!